Failed to running StackSaga Admin server
After running the stacksaga-admin-1.0.0.jar executable jar I am getting this error.
2024-06-20T12:57:11.128+05:30 ERROR 3004 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure while processing configuration class [org.stacksaga.admin.StackSagaAdmin]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:251) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:197) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:165) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:416) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:349) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:118) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:788) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.5.jar!/:3.2.5]
        at org.stacksaga.admin.StackSagaAdmin.main(StackSagaAdmin.java:25) ~[!/:1.0.0]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[stacksaga-admin-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[stacksaga-admin-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[stacksaga-admin-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: stacksaga-admin-application.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:86) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:189) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:232) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:160) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:100) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:74) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceProcessor.processPropertySource(PropertySourceProcessor.java:92) ~[spring-core-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySourceRegistry.processPropertySource(PropertySourceRegistry.java:75) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:281) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:246) ~[spring-context-6.1.6.jar!/:6.1.6]
        ... 22 common frames omitted



To override the default configurations with your configurations, you have to provide a properties file called stacksaga-admin-application.properties in the directory that your jar file is running on. create that file and include your configurations like the database, security, etc.

